# Function for accessing class object within class

Tags: c++

I have a class called Position, it contains member variables X, Y and Z, and some other public member functions.

```
class Position{
public:
void SetPos(double X, double Y, double Z);
private:
double X, Y, Z; 
};
```

Then I have another class that contains a "Position" as a private member variable.

```
class NewClass{
public:
Postion GetPos();
private:
Position classPos;
};

Position NewClass:GetPos() { return classPos;}
```

What I am trying to do is access classPos in NewClass by using the GetPos function like so:

```
SomeFunction(NewClass.GetPos());
Position new_pos = NewClass.GetPos();
```

However when I do, it always assigns or passes the incorrect values (1e61). I do have the = operator overloaded and when I step in through the function (operator function), the correct values are there,  however on exit it reverts back to the 1e61 values.

Comment: Where are you setting the values?

Comment: This code will not compile due to numerous typos, and the `Position` class definition doesn't look complete. (It's missing members to set and obtain the values.) Please post a **complete, *working* example that reproduces the problem.**

Comment: @0x499602D2 I have member functions like SetPos(double X, double Y, double Z) and the values set are there. It is just through passing and assignment that something goes wrong

Comment: `NewClass` is a type, not a variable. You need a variable of that type, on which to call the method. `NewClass.GetPos()` is just as nonsensical as, say, `int = 1;` (here, too, `int` is a type - you can't assign a value to a type, only to a variable of that type).

Comment: I understand that, I was showing this as an example of what I am doing. I know I need to create a new object NewClass some_name. Then call some_name.GetPos().

Comment: @user2840470 I am voting to close this question because the code you have shown does not demonstrate the problem adequately. One would have to be psychic to debug this problem with the amount of information you have presented. Please see my prior comment.

Comment: Why then are you showing one piece of code, but asking questions about a different one - a piece of code that we can't see? Show the actual code that reproduces the problem. What you have now only remotely resembles C++.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

GetPos is a function that you call on an *object*, not a *class*.

```
NewClass newClassObject;
Position p = newClassObject.GetPos();
SomeFunction(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
I had to change the function to return by reference

```
class NewClass{
const Position& GetPos();
private:
Positon classPos;
};
const Position& NewClass::GetPos() { return classPos;}
```

Comment: Why does that make sense? What difference is the `const&` making here?

Comment: If this does make a difference then this hints that there is a user-defined copy constructor that does something wrong, since returning by value would cause the copy constructor to be invoked to create the copy, while returning by reference would not.

Comment: @cdhowie Wouldn't both his examples(copy initializations and function call) result in copy constructor calls under both circumstances?

Comment: @Pradhan The second, yes. The first depends on whether `SomeFunction()` accepts its argument by reference.

Comment: @cdhowie Ah right. Since OP was mentioning `operator=`, argument by value seemed more likely - that was the better fitting misconception :)

Comment: @Pradhan Right. Ultimately, this is a flawed answer to a flawed question.

Answer (score 0):

(I am assuming `Position` is a class where the default copy constructor will not suffice, i.e., a shallow copy will lead to undefined behaviour. Am also overlooking the obvious typos as you indicated in the comments that you are aware of them.)

The assignment operator overload does not get invoked in either of your examples. Passing an object to a function by value invokes either the move or copy constructor, assuming the copy wasn't elided out. The second example

```
Position new_pos = some_new_class.GetPos();
```

is an example of [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). This statement doesn't invoke `operator=` either. Inspite the of the syntax, what it actually uses, since the rhs has type `Position`, is the copy constructor. In general, copy initialization will only consider non-explicit constructors and user-defined conversions.